# Scrapy SitemapSpider get additional information from sitemap

Tags: python, scrapy, sitemap

I try to use [SitemapSpider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#sitemapspider) to parse sitemap. Please see the following code, How can I get additional information in the parse function from the sitemap. For example, the sitemap already contain `news:keywords` and `news:stock_tickers`. How do I get those data and pass to the parse function?

```
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
class ReutersSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'reuters'
    sitemap_urls = ['https://www.reuters.com/sitemap_news_index1.xml']

    def parse(self, response):
        # How can I get data like news:stock_tickers from sitemap for this item? I only have url from the sitemap here.
        yield {
            'title': response.css("title ::text").extract_first(),
            'url': response.url
        }
```

Sitemap item example

```
<url>
<loc>
https://www.reuters.com/article/micron-tech-results/update-6-micron-sales-profit-miss-estimates-as-chip-glut-hurts-prices-idUSL3N1YN50N
</loc>
<news:news>
<news:publication>
<news:name>Reuters</news:name>
<news:language>eng</news:language>
</news:publication>
<news:publication_date>2018-12-19T03:50:10+00:00</news:publication_date>
<news:title>
UPDATE 6-Micron sales, profit miss estimates as chip glut hurts prices
</news:title>
<news:keywords>Headlines,Industrial Conglomerates</news:keywords>
<news:stock_tickers>
SEO:000660,SEO:005930,TYO:6502,NASDAQ:AAPL,NASDAQ:AMZN
</news:stock_tickers>
</news:news>
</url>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SitemapSpider` is specialized for extracting links and nothing else, so it doesn't provide the means for extracting additional data from a sitemap.

You *could* overwrite its [`_parse_sitemap`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/sitemap.py#L34) method to pass the data in generated requests' meta.
However, if your sitemap is simple enough, it might be simpler to just do your own sitemap parsing.

Comment: How to do my own sitemap parsing? You mean do not use Scrapy framework? I'm very new to this, please advice!

Comment: I mean, use basic `Spider` instead of `SitemapSpider`, and generate requests yourself.

Comment: I really need someone who can help me to start. How can I contact you?

Comment: I just left you a message in the irc.

Answer (score 1):

AS @stranac pointed out, Scrapy is developed (and all related spiders) to get information from the web, and Sitemaps are a good way to find those links into the products on each website, but it isn't really good at actually crawling information directly from the sitemaps.

So as suggested, you need to create your own spider, which should be like this:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from lxml import etree


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'sitemap_example'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request('https://www.reuters.com/sitemap_news_index1.xml')

    def parse(self, response):
        sitemap = etree.fromstring(response.body)
        for child in sitemap.getchildren():
            inner_children = child.getchildren()
            news_child = [x for x in inner_children if 'news' in x.tag]
            if not news_child:
                continue
            else:
                news_child = news_child[0]
                stock_child = [x for x in news_child if 'stock_tickers' in x.tag]
                keywords_child = [x for x in news_child if 'keywords' in x.tag]
                title_child = [x for x in news_child if 'title' in x.tag]
                if stock_child:
                    yield {
                        'stock_tickers': stock_child[0].text,
                        'keywords': keywords_child[0].text,
                        'title': title_child[0].text,
                    }
```

Please let me know what do you think and if I can help you with anything else.